# Removing a class from an element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I think I'm VERY close - but not quite there...
In short:  I am trying to show the bottom portion of a table (step2) depending upon the existence of data in an input field in the top portion of the table (step1).
I am trying to use removeClass via jQuery for the initial load of the document AND on change.

PLEASE NOTE:
INCLUDED HERE ARE MULTIPLE SCRIPTS - NOT AS AN INDICATION OF MY INEXPERIENCE, BUT TO SHOW THAT I HAVE BEEN WORKING HARD TO RESOLVE THIS AND THESE ARE MY MULTIPLE TRIES...

http://jsfiddle.net/SUrU9/2/

```
<table>
<tr align="center">
    <td colspan="2">
        <hr>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="Step1ID">
    <td valign="middle">Step 1 Data:</td>
    <td valign="middle">
        <input type="text" id="Step1Data" name="Step1Data" size="8" maxlength="8" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
    <td colspan="2">
        <hr>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="Step2ID" class="hideS2">
    <td>Step2 Data:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="Step2Data" name="Step2Data" size="8" maxlength="8" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
    <td colspan="2">
        <hr>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>


$(document).ready(function () {
var Step1Data = $("#Step1Data").val();
if (Step1Data === '') {} else {
    $('tr').removeClass('hideS2');
}

$(document).on('change', '#Step1ID', function () {
    var Step1Data = $.trim(("#Step1Data").val());
    if (Step1Data === '') {} else {
        $('tr').removeClass('hideS2');
    }
});

$(body).on('change', '#Step1ID', function () {
    var Step1Data = $.trim(("#Step1Data").val());
    if (Step1Data === '') {} else {
        $('tr').removeClass('hideS2');
    }
});

$('#Step1ID').on('change', '#Step1Data', function () {
    var Step1Data = $.trim(("#Step1Data").val());
    if (Step1Data === '') {} else {
        $('tr').removeClass('hideS2');
    }
});

$("Step1Data").blur(function () {
    var Step1Data = $.trim(("#Step1Data").val());
    if (Step1Data === '') {} else {
        $('tr').removeClass('hideS2');
    }
});

$("Step1ID").focusout(function () {
    var Step1Data = $.trim(("#Step1Data").val());
    if (Step1Data === '') {} else {
        $('tr').removeClass('hideS2');
    }
});
});


 .hideS2 {
 display: none;
 }
```

Comment: Javascript uses `!==` for inequality, not `<>`.

Comment: Your variables do not exist.

Comment: Please provide fiddle if possible?

Comment: Overall thought it was a decent question.  Sad to see stackoverflow getting very elitist against new members.  +1 for having the courage to ask a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to check to see if the Step1Info and Step2Info variables contain any data and if they do reveal the next part of the table? The reason it isn't working is because the if statements run when the document is ready. Once the user actually fills in the parts of the form you want to check for data the jQuery is never told to check again. What I would do is remove the hidden class when the user changes focus to the step before, or make them do something that triggers an event to remove the class. Here is some code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Top Instruction</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Step1Info</td></tr>
    <tr id="Step2_id" class="hide"><td>Step2Info</td></tr>
    <tr id="Step3_id" class="hide"><td>Step3Info</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bottom Instruction</td></tr>
</tbody> 
</table>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('focus', '#textbox1', function() {
        $("#Step2_id").removeClass("hide");
    });

    $(document).on('focus', '#textbox2', function() {
        $("#Step3_id").removeClass("hide");
    });
});
</script>

<style>
.hide {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

If you want to wait until the user actually puts something into the form you could use:

```
$(document).on('change', '#textbox1', function() {
    $("#Step2_id").removeClass("hide");
});
```

I had to take some liberties and guess how you actually had things set up. I hope this at least helps you understand why things aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is using the tag `trbody`, which is invalid. get rid of those tags and move the `id` and `class` to the `<tr>` tags.

Also change the code:

```
$("tbody").removeClass('hideS2');
```

to

```
$(".hideS2").removeClass('hideS2');
```

Comment: No need to downvote when we are trying to help you.

Comment: He didn't downvote - I did. This does not provide an actual solution to the problem. OP lacks basic understanding of this issue and this question is very ambiguous. These sort of answers promote these sort of questions that will likely benefit no-one facing an issue in the future - all they'll do is teach users to behave like this and ask these sort of questions. Please don't take this personally, I appreciate your attempt to help OP and I know you were just trying to help :) Downvotes indicate usefulness or lack of it. I only downvoted because I did not find this answer useful.

Comment: @Benjamin: Perhaps you could offer that advice to the OP instead of just downvoting everything and bashing the Good Samaritans. My answer is to get rid of the extraneous invalid HTML which is certainly at least a partial solution to the problem.

Comment: @jalynn2 This is how we normally discuss etiquette on the site. The down-vote was aimed to show lack of usefulness imo, but in general answering very ambiguous questions is not a good idea - not only is it not rewarding but it's also encouraging the sort of behavior of 'debug my code' questions we'd like to avoid If you feel that I've done something inappropriate here you are _very_ welcome to take this to [meta]. If the community feels that I've done something inappropriate I'll gladly change my ways :)

Comment: @Sooze invalid tags syntax (use an HTML validator), using operators that don't even exist in JavaScript, using variables you don't show where you get all show a very basic lack of understanding that is not related to removing a class from a `tbody`. You should consider first mastering basic JavaScript and HTML before attempting to do that - it'll be a lot less frustrating and we'll be able to actually help you and help you quicker. The less clear the problem is the worse are the answers you get. I recommend the official MDN JavaScript tutorial or Eloquent JavaScript :) Good luck!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SUrU9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure how you're getting your variables, I just guessed.  I added some check marks to the instructions to show that the step was completed.  Here is a fiddle to my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BBaaA/

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Step1_ck").click(function () {
        $("#Step2_id").toggleClass("hideS2");
    });

    $("#Step2_ck").click(function () {
        $("#Step3_id").toggleClass("hideS3");
    });
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.hideS2 {
    display: none;
}
.hideS3 {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Top Instruction</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Step1_id" class="hideS1">
        <td>Step1Info</td>
        <td>
            <input id="Step1_ck" type="checkbox">
            <td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Step2_id" class="hideS2">
        <td>Step2Info</td>
        <td>
            <input id="Step2_ck" type="checkbox">
            <td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Step3_id" class="hideS3">
        <td>Step3Info</td>
        <td>
            <input id="Step3_ck" type="checkbox">
            <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bottom Instruction</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```